# Flutter : Fetch audio from recorded video

Tags: flutter, dart, audio, video, flutter-dependencies

I have a feature to implement in Flutter. I have to record user video and fetch audio from that for next level verification. Does anyone have any idea about this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: My requirement is to record a video in which user will speak something. I have to fetch that speech and match it on back end (kind of authentication process). @Community

Comment: @Ahmad Raza yes I want extract the audio(speech) from the video.

Answer (score 2):

I assume you are trying to extract audio only from Video, you can achive this by using the [ffmpeg](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_ffmpeg) package.

Import this package in your project add the following lines in your `android\build.gradle`

```
ext.flutterFFmpegPackage = 'full'
```

flutter_ffmpeg provides eight packages that include different sets of external libraries. These packages are named according to the external libraries included in them. From documentation you can see which libraries are enabled in each package. And you can use according to your need, so if you need to change full to specific one you can do this but here i am using full to make your work done.

With below code snippet you can extract audio from video

```
 final FlutterFFmpeg FFmpeg = FlutterFFmpeg();
    FFmpeg.execute(
        "-i /storage/emulated/0/download/Test_video.mp4 -map 0:a -acodec libmp3lame /storage/emulated/0/download/test3.mp3").then((rc) =>
    {
      print("FFmpeg process exited with rc $rc.")
    }
```

Print statement should return 0 on success, Also i am using testvideo from my own storage you need to change this according to your storage location.